# Is conversion to a quadratic form possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to represent the expression $(Ax+b)^TS(Ax+b)$ in the form of a quadratic form $(x+e)^TF(x+e) + K$ for some $e$, $F$ and $K$, and matrix $A$ with dimensions $m\times n$, $m>n$.

*Note:* I have thought the following will do. $(Ax+b) = A(x+A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b)$, then $e=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$ and $F = A^TSA$. However this does not work for a matrix $A$, which has more rows then columns, since $AA^T$ is singular in this case.

Comment: Obviously, you only need $Ae=b$ to have a solution for your technique to work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not sure that I have understood your comment. My technique will not work, becase $AA^T$ is singular, if $m>n$.

Comment: My point is, you don't need $(AA^T)^{-1}b$, you just need $e$ such that $Ae=b$. But there still isn't always such an $e$.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Toying with a $1$-dimensional $x$ and $A,b$ chosen in such a way that the equation mentioned by Thomas, $Ae=b$, has no solutions quickly gives examples, where the desired form cannot be achieved (unless $S$ "cures" this problem). What may be always possible is to write the expression in the form
$$(x+e)^TF(x+e)+K,$$ where $K$ is a constant. In other words it may be possible to pick $e$ in such a way that the linear term will be ok, but the constant needs some help. I dare not conjecture that this would always happen, because in my case we are dealing with the question of our ability...

Comment: (cont'd) to express a linear functional on $1$-d space in a given way. My toying does suggest that the pseudoinverse of $SA$ may play a role. It's getting late, and I don't know the pseudoinverse stuff well at all, so I call it a night.

Comment: Also, if $Ax\neq b$ for all $x$, then $Ax+b\neq0$ for all $x$. Should it happen that $S$ is positive definite, then we always have $(Ax+b)^TS(Ax+b)>0$ whereas $(x+e)^TF(x+e)$ always achieves zero at $x=-e$. Therefore you will need an additive constant in those cases.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you guys. A constant is indeed possible and welcome in my case, I've forgotten to add it. I''ll adjust the statement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See previous comment. Additionaly it would be much better if $e$ will not depend on $b$. This is because originally I have a sum of such terms, and the $S$ is the parameter for all of them. If $e$ depends on $b$ then I'll end up with different $F$ for each term, which is not perfect.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews :( $e$, such that $Ae=b$ will not work, since this is an overdetermined system in my case. So there is no such $e$. And this probably means that it is not possible to convert initial expression to a quadratic form, or?

Comment: My point isn't that you can always find such $e$, my point is, when you can find such $e$, you are done. If I thought it solved your problem, I would have made it an answer, not a comment. My point is, your long messy $(AA^T)^{-1}$ computation is really just trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I've understood it this way, I'm sorry if I expressed myself wrongly. Meanwhile, if such an $e$ cannot be found, does it actually neccesarily mean I cannot perform the conversion?